# How can I connect directly to a mobile device over 3G?

Tags: mobile, connectivity, 3g

I'd like to be able to deploy a lightweight web server on my mobile device (android) but there are obviously NAT issues with respect to the mobile provider's network. Is there anyway I can make my device publicly available/addressable over the internet?

Answer (score 3):

A Nokia research team did something similar to this and used a gateway, which was mapped to the public URL with DNS, to provide a means of always accessing the phone (which had an app to then send the HTTP message to the Mobile webserver).

I would imagine this would also have the advantage of allowing you provide some sort of controlled response from the gateway itself even if the phone is not switched on/in coverage.

Details at: http://wiki.opensource.nokia.com/projects/MWS:FAQ#So_how_does_my_phone_get_a_URL.3F